# MYSQL nested select query from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, nested

What I am trying to do is select each distinct `column1` value from `table1` and then select all the columns from those rows returned from the above. Is this possible at all?

What I have so far, however, nothing is returned:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table1)`

I've thought about putting a unique/distinct restriction in the `where` clause of the query:

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE some_unique_determiner column1`

Any ideas how I could go about achieving the desired output?

Comment: Sample data and expected result will help us to understand better. I believe you want to find first/last record in each group

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve here! To me it seems that the result of what you described is simply the same as `select * from table`

Comment: I apologise for the way the question was question, but I am a beginner. But I think I've reached my desired output with thanks to @VR46, who pointed me in the right direction. I needed to group it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your next posts, it will be better if you post your table structures, input and desired out put so it will be easier for us to understand.

If I did understand, there is one of two options:

Either you have duplicates, and you want to eliminate them so your correct query should be

```
select distinct COLUMNa,COLUMNb,COLUMNc... ETC
```

which will drop duplicates(that the entire row is the same).

Or you want to eliminate rows that have the same column1 and it doesn't matter if all the rest is the same or not.
In that case, You need to tell us which one of the result you want to keep, The up to date one,the older, random ETC.. because right now its impossible to make you a query that selects all the columns after you distinct, since all the duplicates will return like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 IN(SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE)
```

Which is a wrong query since it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Will do in the future. A simple `...GROUP BY column1` did the trick of returning distinct `column1` values

Comment: @VR46 I know, thats what I said , that it is not correct because it doesn't do anything and its equal to select * from table. I wanted to explain him that his request is now exactly correct

Answer (score 0):

Ok so answering my own question. What I need to do was to group the data by `column1`, without use of a nested query. Many thanks to @VR46 for the help.

`SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY column1`

Returned all columns from each unique value from column1

Comment: You are using a MySQL (mis)features that is explicitly documented to produce "indeterminate" results.  You should not have columns in the `select` that are not-aggregated and not in the `group by`.